# How to sort a collection in Laravel

Tags: laravel, collections

I doing sortBy function to sort but i can't use it as sorted by For.

```
$this->journey->journey_item = $this->journey->journey_items->sortBy('activation_date');
dump($journey_items); //// sorted list

for($i = 0;$i < Count($this->journey->journey_item);$i++){
   dump("#".$i." ".$this->journey->journey_item[$i]->activation_date);
}
```

When it entered in For, it becomes as unsorted.
Where am i doing wrong ?
What can i do ?

Also, I have created a new collection and tried to equalize it, again it didn't

Answer (score 1):

Try with foreach. when you use collection sort it'll sort your array not `key`.. as I see you're using `key [$i]`.

Use foreach

```
foreach($this->journey->journey_item as $journey_item){
   dump($journey_item);
}
```

Or you use as below.

```
$this->journey->journey_item = $this->journey->journey_items->sortBy(function ($journey_item) {
    return $journey_item->activation_date;
});
```

Comment: For second solution, it gave me the error; asort() expects parameter 2 to be int, object given

Comment: how to specify the activation_date into sortBy funct